# How to Add Sitemap Automatically from Wordpress to Blogger

Tags: javascript, wordpress, feed, sitemap, blogger

How to make sitemap / list ordered by category like http://goo.gl/XnFIsM (wordpress version) on blogspot?

I want to add sitemap automatically from wordpress to blogger.

Wordpress use php, blogger use html.

They are also different feed formats.

Answer (score 0):

Blogger doesn't allow such sitemaps. Blogger creates Sitemap in XML format automatically. Following url have been added as an example.

For **blogspot** blogs

http://example.blogspot.com/sitemap.xml

If you have **custom domain**.

http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml